how to redirect to a url from a page in google sites
Google has indexed an old (non-google sites) version of my site with a url like /old.html from several months ago that may still be linked to from other web sites.
How can I redirect /old.html (the url indexed) to a new page in the same domain of my google site like a page named /New ?
Right now it returns a 404 which is not great for usability. Redirecting would be much better.
Background: standard web pages can be redirected via 302 permanent from an HTTP code from the web server or 301 temporary. Once loaded, pages can redirect using <META http-equiv="refresh content="0; url=https://www.a.example/"> in the  element, or a JavaScript function can be called like <body onload="redirect()"> using either <script language=javascript> function redirect(){window.location.href = "https://www.a.example";}</script> which simulates a mouse click or window.location.replace("https://www.a.example"); that simulates an HTTP redirect. None of these methods are available in Google Sites.
The old version of google sites used to have a URL Redirector gadget but that version of google sites is deprecated.
In a page I can "insert" an "embed" of Javascript and under Pages I can create new pages and links and full page embeds but it's not obvious how to use them for this purpose.
